# SSIS Package Isolation Level vs Stored Procedure Isolation level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I have created an SSIS Package which executes a stored procedure. The SSIS Package has the Isolation Level set to Serializable. The Stored Procedure has only one transaction and the transactional Isolation Level of this stored procedure is set to Read Uncommitted.

Will the Isolation Level of the SSIS Package override the Isolation Level of the stored procedure and execute the transaction with Serializable Level?

How can I assure that the stored procedure and the SSIS Package will execute both with the Isolation Level Read Uncommitted? What should I set for Transaction Option?

Comment: Why cant  we set only TSQL isolation level and remove ssis isolation level

Answer (score 0):

> How can I assure that the stored procedure and the SSIS Package will
>   execute both with the Isolation Level Read Uncommitted?

You can set both isolation levels to Read Uncommitted.